# Angular NX mono repo: How to include a file from node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript

We've got an NX Angular monorepo. I've got a library that depends on Pendo. It does not come with a Node package, but there's a typed definition here.

However, the problem is that this type definition does not export anything; so the usual "import ... from 'pendo-io-browser'" won't work. I believe I need to include this file somewhere in a tsconfig file so it's picked up.

So, in the tsconfig.json of my library I added ../../node_modules/@types/pendo-io-browser/index.d.ts. Then, I got an error in the same tsconfig: Referenced project '..../tsconfig.lib.json' must have setting "composite": true When I added that, the errors that it could not find pendo were got, but I got a bunch of other errors, as it suddenly could not find other dependencies.

So, I tried to add it to the root tsconfig.base.json. However, that didn't work, still getting "Cannot find name pendo".

Also tried import 'pendo-io-browser' which seems to work in VS Code, but when compiling I get:

SyntaxError: D:\projects\app\node_modules@types\pendo-io-browser\index.d.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Finally, I added "pendo-io-browser" to the `types` array in the tsconfig.*.json of my library, which resolved the errors in VS Code. However, when compiling my app, I still got the error "cannot find namespace 'pendo'". Tried to add the same to `types` in tsconfig.base.json in the root, the tsconfig.app.json of the application, no luck.

I'm a bit stuck, as this seems like a trivial thing to do.

Thanks in advance.